# Change the display on my file tab

Tags: visual-studio-2008

all the files i work with are displayed as tabs in visual studio.  I have classes in a folder and the tab is displaying like this:

App_Code/...onlypartofclassname.cs

instead of the full class name.

any way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change this without installing an add-in (something like [Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/)). My understanding is that VS only has this behaviour for files in web sites, not for files that belong to a project (web applications, class libraries, console apps, etc...) where only the filename is shown.